# How to execute a set of JavaScript code only if HTML form validation is succesfull

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form with some fields and a submit button. couple of fields are mandatory. I have a set of JavaScript code which i need to execute only if the form validation is successful. If there is some validation error on the form, the JavaScript code shall not execute. Below is the sample code:

```
<form id="sampleForm" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="firstname" required />
<input type="text" id="secondname" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
/*JavaScript*/
$("#sampleForm").submit(function(){
//Set of JavaScript code to execute if validation is success.
});
```

For me above JavaScript code does not work.
Please help!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with "validation"? Shouldn't there be some code performing validation in your example?

Comment: It is a normal HTML form validation which happens when a user clicks on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> But if i use `$("#sampleForm").submit()` to submit the form, the form gets submitted but if i write function inside submit() (`$("#sampleForm").submit(function(){ //Set of JavaScript code to execute if validation is success. });`) then nothing happens !

That function is called when the `submit` event is fired, but the event isn't fire when the controls are invalid because the form won't be submitted.

The individual form controls get an `invalid` event when the user tries to submit the form when they're invalid. You can use that to provide feedback beyond what the browser supplies if you like:

```js
$("#sampleform")
    .on("submit", function() {
    alert("Got the 'submit' event; form is being submitted");
  })
  .find("input, select")
  .on("invalid", function() {
    // Will fire for *EACH* invalid control
    alert("Validation failed");;
  });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pc0qsjn/) (Stack Snippets don't allow form submission even when it's cancelled.)

In case you need to submit the form programmatically (by calling `submit`), you can use `checkValidity` first to see if the form is valid:

```
// When submitting programmatically
var form = $("#sampleForm");
if (form[0].checkValidity()) {
    form.submit();
}
```

Side note: When you use jQuery to submit the form (above), `submit` event handlers will be called. But if you use the DOM to submit the form (`$("#sampleForm)[0].submit()`), they won't be.

Comment: instead of checkValidity() i used valid() and it worked for me. i think i should accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just write a submit handler and execute your codes.

```
$("#sampleForm").submit(function(){
 // Your code.
})
```

Submit handler triggers only when you complete the validation by HTML5 custom validator.

Here is a demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/9ky8Z/118/

Answer (score 0):

Html5 form have [**checkValidity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) method.Also since it is a form and button type is submit it will default throw an error pop up if it is not valid. `checkValidity` method return a boolean value true if it is valid. You can take a look in this method for further your job

```js
$("#sampleForm").submit(function(e) {
  
  var result = document.getElementById('firstname').checkValidity()
  console.log(result) // will log true

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sampleForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" required />
  <input type="text" id="secondname" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If the form controls are invalid, no `submit` event is sent (and the form isn't submitted). So calling `checkValidity` inside a `submit` handler is pointless.

Comment: (Which is why I deleted my answer saying much the same as the above.) Thinking about it, though, there's one case where it wouldn't be entirely pointless, because of an oddity (in my view) about jQuery: If you use jQuery to submit the form: `$("#sampleForm).submit()`. This is because jQuery triggers submit handlers when you do that, unlike the DOM which does not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers! 
I tried each one of your's solution which helped me to reach to my solution. Below worked for me:

```
if($("#sampleForm").valid()){
$("#sampleForm").submit();
//Set of JavaScript code to execute.
}
```